# Function pointer to class method

Tags: c++

I need some help with using a function pointer to another class method in a class but I'm not sure how to make it able to call any class method.

The code is probably very wrong and that's because I'm pretty confused by how it works, but hopefully this code snipped will explain what I want to be able to do.

```
#ifndef BUTTON_INPUT_HPP
#define BUTTON_INPUT_HPP

#include"../InputComponent.hpp"

class ButtonInput : public InputComponent {
public:
    template<typename C>
                            ButtonInput(void(C::*f)(), C* object);
    virtual void            update(World& world, GraphicsComponent& graphics, Actor& actor);
private:
    void (C::*func)();
};

#endif
```

The update function checks if the button is clicked, and should call func() if it is.

Comment: I would recommend against using plain function pointers, instead use std::function and std::bind.

Comment: WOuld it be possible to pass a Button type, rather than template?

Comment: You may look at design pattern: [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how to store a function pointer to a member function along with a pointer to an instance. The stored function can later be called using `call()`.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename C>
class FuncHolder {
public:
    FuncHolder(void (C::*f)(), C* object) : func(f), c(object) {}
    void call() { (c->*func)(); } // Make the call.
private:
    void (C::*func)(); // Pointer to member function.
    C* c;              // Pointer to object.
};

// Example class with member function.
struct Foo {
    void test() { std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    FuncHolder<Foo> f(&Foo::test, &foo);

    f.call();
}
```

Comment: This is what I had in mind, but I couldn't get it to work, must have a made a mistake somewhere.
Thanks!